# Recaptcha Contact form 7 and Mailchimp form on one page WP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

Hi I have 2 forms on one page.
Contact form 7 and a Mailchimp form

Mailchimp form recaptcha does not work because I think it is appearing twice:

Contact Form 7

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20170213115309/recaptcha__en.js"></script>
```

Mailchimp form

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20170213115309/recaptcha__en.js"></script>
```

Errors in console:

```
Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty
```

On pages without contact form 7 the Mailchimp recaptcha works fine.

Any ideas? do I have to deregister the contact form 7 script in functions file? Or can I do with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a hack workaround.

By loading recaptcha on all pages except the contact form page so contact form 7 and mailchimp share same script and not load twice. I added this to the head.php in WP

```
if( !is_page( array( 'contact-australia',))){ ?>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async ></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use Contact Form 7 MailChimp Extension https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension/

Comment: Thanks for your input but I have 2 separate forms. Contact form 7 goes to company enquires email and then I have a mailchimp signup form - both on the same page.

Comment: What plugin for mailchimp you ara using? I cant found recaptcha in MailChimp for WordPress - this is best plugin for mailchimp.

Comment: My solution based on using for mailchimp Contact Form 7 and Extension for mailchimp. Please look to the screenshots https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension/screenshots/ - this is example how to config Contact Form with mailchimp extinsion.